# search slide and get page element text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

My script searches one specific slide in a presentation. Then it gets the text from the first page element. This page element is a shape with only one word. After this, when I put strings before and after this page element text, there is a break in the text.

```
function readShapeText() {
   var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
   var slides = presentation.getSlides();
   
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    
       if(slides[i].getObjectId() == 'mySlideId'){
 
         var pageElement = slides[i].getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString();
          
       }
   }
    
   var myModifiedElement = "My_" + pageElement + "_is_cool";
}
```

The output is with a break, but I need in one line:

> My_TestElement
>
> _is_cool

How can I eliminate or suppress the break? And is there a better way to find a specific slide without using "for loop" f.e. like presentation.openSlideById(xxxxxx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about these answers?

#### Q1: How can I eliminate or suppress the break?

It seems that the end of texts is always given `\n`. This can be also seen from values retrieved by `Slides.Presentations.get()`. So if you want to retrieve the values without `\n`, you can do it using `replace("\n", "")`.

#### Q2: Is there a better way to find a specific slide without using "for loop" f.e. like presentation.openSlideById(xxxxxx)?

How about the following sample script? It retrieved the specific slide using `filter()`, because the key of `objectId` is included in the array. And `replace("\n", "")` was also used.

```
function readShapeText() {
  var mySlideId = "mySlideId"; // Please input this.
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var slide = slides.filter(function(e){return e.getObjectId() == mySlideId})[0];
  var pageElement = slide.getPageElements()[0].asShape().getText().asString().replace("\n", "");
  var myModifiedElement = "My_" + pageElement + "_is_cool";
  Logger.log(myModifiedElement)
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again, Tanaike :)

Comment: @Roberto B Welcom. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.